# Is it possible in kotlin serialization without using intermediate options to immediately convert Map <String, Any> to a model

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization

This case is in the JS version (Properties.decodeFromMap (map)), but for android, I have not seen.

It can also be solved using Jackson

The object in which I should get a rather complex type, the approximate form of the fields is much larger

```
data class BaseModel (val value: String,val options: Options,val type: Type ...)
```

The main thing I need to get directly from `Map <String, Any>` in BaseModel

Comment: Do you need to convert an instance of `Map<String, Any>` to an instance of `BaseModel`? If so how is this related to serialization or Jackson or JS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to use the properties from the kotlinx-serialization-properties package, it turns out that it is also distributed for android

Answer (score 1):

This was quite a ride through deep kotlin but I got a minimal example.

```
data class BaseModel(var a:Int, var b:String)

...

//during onCreate 
val map=mutableMapOf<String,Any>()
map.put("a",1)
map.put("b","b")
test(map)

...
fun test(map:MutableMap<String,Any>){
        val params=BaseModel::class.constructors.toList()[0].parameters.associateBy({ it }, { map.get(it.name) })
        val bm=BaseModel::class.constructors.toList()[0].callBy(params)
        println(bm.a)
        println(bm.b)
    }
```

And it prints 1 and b as expected.

A little caveat though, you have to have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath, which you can add by clicking an alert if you're using Android Studio. But if you don't add that dependency, you won't get a compile time error or any warnings in your IDE; the error won't be caught until runtime.